# Trace of Hermitian involutionary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

let $V$ be a Hermitian matrix s.t. $V^2 = I$. Because it's Hermitian, we know that the trace is real. But as it is not necessarily PSD, what does it being involutionary tell us about the trace? I am unsure about the trace of the inverse:
$$tr(V) = \sum_i \lambda_ i = tr(V^{-1}) =\sum_i \lambda_ i^{⁻1} \Longrightarrow |\lambda_i |= 1?$$

Comment: If $V$ is any matrix whatsoever squaring to the identity then its eigenvalues are $\pm 1$.

Comment: Since it is involutionary and symmetric, then the eigenvalues can only be 1 or -1. So, the trace will lie within $\{-n,\ldots,0,\ldots,n\}$. The eigenvalues of the inverse matrix will also only be 1 or -1. The same conclusion will hold for the trace.